# Terragrunt permission denied when try to get hclfmt file from defined location

Tags: terragrunt

I see permission denied error when my terragrunt tries to read the file inside the ecs fargrate docker image , I see that is working when I test it locally . But it gaves error of permission denied when it tries to read the file from ecs docker task

````
time=2021-07-28T08:48:10Z level=info msg=Formatting hcl file at: /home/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl.
time=2021-07-28T08:48:10Z level=info msg=Formatting /home/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl
time=2021-07-28T08:48:10Z level=error msg=open /home/terragrunt/terragrunt.hcl: permission denied
time=2021-07-28T08:48:10Z level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1```
````

Comment: This was a permission issue inside the docker image resolved it by providing it the proper permission and then created a sublink to run the process ln -s /home/atlantis/terragrunt /usr/local/bin/terragrunt

Answer (score 0):

If you face the same error while deploying the  resource in ecs fargrate atlantis docker image make sure you always use a sublink to run terragrunt as atlantis entrypoint docker restrict the access of the files and expect the process to run as a sublink.